# Can I calculate average time spent per user on a third party widget?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm currently developing a widget that can be embedded on any blog or news portal. I wish to calculate average time spent per user on my widget only. Wondering if there is any easy way to do this. I believe I won't be able to use third party analytics tool like Google Analytics as the clients would have already installed this on their site and it may conflict with their analytics as well. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the widget in an iframe hosted under a different URL?

Comment: Yes, it sends the request to my domain and fetch the json object which then gets embedded in my iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google analytics with different UA and unique tracker object name on any page. Which will separate your data collection without conflicts of site owner GA.